# Which column should I pick up as secondary index in this dynamodb table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table with the following attributes:

```
  PurchaseOrderNumber (partition key)
  CustomerID  
  PurchaseDate
```

**TotalPurchaseValue** is what my application must retrieve items from the table to calculate the total value of purchases for a particular customer over a date range. What secondary index should I add to the table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a **Global Secondary Index** where the **partition key** will be **CustomerID** and **sort key** will be **PurchaseDate**. By this, you can perform query operations on a particular customer by CustomerID within a date range of PurchaseDate. You can try out the query code below in AWS lambda IDE :)

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table_name = "your_table_name"
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
    customer_id = 1
    start_date = "2019-12-10"
    end_date = "2019-12-16"

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('CustomerID').eq(customer_id) & 
            Key('PurchaseDate').between(start_date, end_date)                                                            
    )
    return response
```

Comment: Thank you Abdullah for the input, can you further explain if I can choose PurchaseDate as the partition key and CustomerID as the sort key? by selecting like that, I first limit the date range of PurchaseDate, and then with the sort on CustomerID I can get the Customer needed. By the way, what is the difference of Global and Local index?

Comment: Based on your requirement in the question, I think it won't be efficient to make PurchaseDate as the partition key and CustomerID as the sort key. Please have a look at this article which I believe will answer all your questions :) 

https://medium.com/brainstation23/break-the-ice-with-dynamodb-5302e7456d2a#e690